# 18.04 server, does new intaller supports mdadm (RAID install)? Did not find the option

Tags: 18.04

Only allows select (if you hit 'manual' option) one disk for installation and do not see previously created mdadm raid array.

Answer (score 0):

As per https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes

The next generation Subiquity server installer, brings the comfortable live session and speedy install of Ubuntu Desktop to server users at last.

N.B., If you require LVM, RAID, multipath, vlans, bonds, or the ability to re-using existing partitions, you will want to continue to use the alternate installer which can be downloaded from http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04/beta-2/

The new installer does not have that built in yet.